# Seeking for a counterexample where the convergence of the series of derivatives isn't uniform

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem_on_differentiation), regarding Fubini's termwise differentiation theorem, if I change the hypothesis of $f_k$ increasing I have to use a stricter condition like uniform convergence of the series of the $f_k'$ almost everywhere. That means there exists $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x), f_k:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ increasing where the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k'(x)$ is not uniform to $f'(x)$ almost everywhere, since this condition is stricter.

This concept is kind of new to me, so: Am I interpreting this correctly? If yes, what would be a counterexample, i.e., an example where $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}, f_k:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ increasing, $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x)$ , $f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k'(x)$ almost everywhere but only pointwise and not uniformly.

Comment: You didn't tell us what $f$ is.

Comment: Oh, that's true! I'm deeply sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $[0,1]$ define $f_k(x)= x^k/k^2$ for $k=1,2,\dots.$ Then each $f_k$ is increasing and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x)$ converges uniformly on $[0,1].$ But

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k'(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{k-1}/k$$

does not converge uniformly on $[0,1].$